# Reading a file from OSGI bundle returns a different format for input stream

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream, osgi-bundle

I am trying to read the resource file from OSGI bundle following is my code snippet :

```
InputStream in;
URL url;

BundleContext bc = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ReportUtil.class).getBundleContext(); // ReportUtil is the name of the class

 url = bc.getBundle().getResource("sample_report.jrxml"); // URL is returned as /sample_report.jrxml
 InputStream dataStream ;
 dataStream= url.openStream();// Input Stream is      java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream@d112491
```

What is the meaning of java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream ?

I need to use the data stream in jasper compiler report which takes input as InputStream , is there a way to convert java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream to an InputStream

Answer (score 0):

It already [is an InputStream](http://www.cs.rit.edu/usr/local/pub/swm/jdoc7/java/util/zip/ZipFile.ZipFileInflaterInputStream.html) - see the class hierarchy.  Just pass it to Jasper Reports.

Comment: I am trying that already e.g.                     JasperCompileManager.compileReport(dataStream)                                      And it shows a big exception trace so I thought there is compatibility mismatch between these two formats